# Finding All Invariant Subspaces of Given Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm making my way through Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* and I'm a bit stumped by this exercise. Any help would be appreciated.

Define $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^{n})$ (a linear transformation from the field $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ to itself) as $T(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) = (x_{1},2x_{2},...,nx_{n})$. Find all invariant subspaces of $T$.

I haven't gotten far on this at all, I mostly just stated the definition of invariant subspace, but I haven't been able to get much farther.

First I suppose $S$ was an invariant subspace, then for $s\in S$, $T(s)\in S$. First I let $e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{n}$ be a standard basis for $\mathbb{F}^{n}$. Then there exists scalars such that $s=\alpha_{1}e_{1} + \alpha_{2}e_{2}+...+\alpha_{n}e_{n}$. Then, $T(s) = T(\alpha_{1}e_{1} + \alpha_{2}e_{2}+...+\alpha_{n}e_{n}) = \alpha_{1}e_{1} + 2\alpha_{2}e_{2} +...+n\alpha_{n}e_{n}$. I feel like this is the right start but I can't figure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

*(partial answer in characteristic 0)*

The matrix of $T$ is diagonal so you are getting a decomposition into eigenvectors for free.

If the field has characteristic zero then all $n$ eigenvalues are distinct. The invariant 1-dimensional subspaces are the coordinate axes. The invariant $k$-dimensional subspaces are the $k$-hyperplanes spanned by the origin and any choice of $k$ standard basis vectors.