# Find all invariant subspaces of $T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,...nx_n)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following problem appears in Chapter 5.A of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> 10. Define $T\in L(F^n)$ by
>
> $$T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,...nx_n)\tag{1}$$
>
> (a) Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$
>
> (b) Find all invariant subspaces of $T$.

Questions have been asked about this problem before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441789/exercise-5-a-10b-find-all-invariant-subspaces-of-t-linear-algebra-done-rig) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548321/finding-all-invariant-subspaces-of-given-transformation) but don't seem to reach a complete and clear answer.

My question is about part b).

**First, let me go through part a).**

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $(x_1,...,x_n)$ an eigenvector.

$$T(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...,nx_n)=\lambda(x_1,...,x_n)\tag{2}$$

and we get the equations

$$x_1=\lambda x_1\tag{1}$$
$$2x_2=\lambda x_2\tag{2}$$
$$(...)$$
$$nx_n=\lambda x_n\tag{3}$$

If $\lambda=0$ then $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=0$ which contradicts our assumption of having an eigenvector (which is by definition not the zero vector).

Thus, $\lambda\neq 0$.

For each $i=1,...,n$ let

1. $\lambda=i$.
2. $x_j=0$ for $j\neq 0$.

Then, all equations are satisfied.

Thus, the eigenvalues are $1,2,...,n$ and the corresponding eigenvectors for each eigenvalue are $(x_1,0,...,0), (0,x_2,0,...,0),...(0,0,...,x_n)$.

**Now here is my attempt at part b**

We have $n$ different eigenvalues $1,...,n$

Consider associated eigenvectors $v_1,...,v_n$.

These vectors are linearly independent and since $\text{dim}(\mathbb{F}^n)=n$ then these vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$.

At this point, I attempted to create two cases: 1) a basis for $W$ can be found among a subset of the $v_1,...,v_n$ and 2) there is no subset of $v_1,...,v_n$ that is a basis for $W$.

**Case 1:** a subset of $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis for $W$.

Let's denote the basis of $W$ as

$$\{ v_{\alpha}: \alpha\in\Gamma\}=\{ v_{\alpha_1},...,v_{\alpha_m}\}$$

where

$$\Gamma=\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m\}\subset\{1,2,...,n\}$$

Let $w\in W$. Then

$$w=\sum_{i=1}^m a_iv_{\alpha_i}$$

$$T(w)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_iT(v_{\alpha_i})=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \alpha_i v_{\alpha_i}\in W$$

Thus, $W$ is invariant under $T$.

At this point we know that every subspace spanned by any subset of the eigenvectors is invariant under T.

Now consider the second case, which considers all the other subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^n$.

**Case 2:** there is no subset of $v_1,...,v_n$ that is a basis for $W$.

The goal here is to find a vector $v\in W$ such that when we apply $T$ to it, it gets mapped outside of $W$.

Does this route have any hope of succeeding?

Comment: If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$, then every vector in $W$ is expressible as a linear combination of the $v_i$'s (the eigenvectors). So, every vector in any basis of $W$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $v_i$'s. So, case 2 (the way you have stated) is not a possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by $L(F^n)$?

Comment: @AnuragA While every vector of W can be expressed as a linear combination of the $v_i$, this doesn't mean that $W$ has a basis that is comprised of the $v_i$. There needs to be some property of the "invariant subspace" that is being used here (which I agree is the crux of the argument, but OP seems to not understand it).

Comment: @ShyamalSayak $L(\mathbb{F}^n)$ is the vector space composed of linear operators on $\mathbb{F}^n$, that is, linear maps from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to see that $\lambda_k = k$ are the distinct eigenvalues, and that $T e_k = \lambda_k e_k$, where $e_k = (...,0,1,0,...)$. Note that the $e_k$ span $\mathbb{F}^n$. It is clear that $\{0\}, \mathbb{F}^n$, and $\operatorname{sp} \{ e_k\}$ are all invariant subspaces which might lead one to suspect that the invariant subspaces are of the form
$\operatorname{sp} \{ e_k\}_{k \in K}$ for some $K \subset \{1,...,n\}$.

Suppose $S$ is a $T$ invariant subspace and $\sum_k \alpha_k e_k \in S$. I want to show that if $\alpha_k \neq 0$, then $e_k \in S$. From this we can immediately conclude the desired result.

Choose an arbitrary $\beta =(\beta_1,...,\beta_n)\in \mathbb{F}^n$ and note that
$(\sum_j \beta_j T^j) \sum_k \alpha_k e_k \in S$. Equivalently,
$\sum_k \alpha_k (\sum_j \beta_j \lambda_k^j) e_k = \sum_k \alpha_k (\gamma_k) e_k \in S$.

Noting that $\gamma = V(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)^T \beta$, where $V$ is the [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrix, we see that we can choose $\beta$ so that $\gamma$ is any vector we want. In particular, we see that if $\alpha_k \neq 0$ then $e_k \in S$.